# zend and jquery/ajax adding and removing rows dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I'm still mastering my zend skills and not that really good in it, but I have been working on some ideas on how can I write a code where by it adds and removes rows dynamically using zend framework something close to this....http://www.amitpatil.me/ajax-table-adding-removing-rows-dynamically-using-javascript-animation/

Any advice on how I could go about this would be really appreciated. A picture found on the net to get an idea

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

heres a jquery version

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add').click(function(){
          $.ajax({
               url:'/yourcontroller/youraction',
               type:'post',
               data:{'division':$('#divison_textbox').val(),'major':$('#major').val()}, /*add the res*/        
               success:function(data){
                 $('#your_tableid tbody').append(data);

              }               

          });

    });
    });

    //in zend youractionAction

    public function youractionAction(){
     $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
            $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
     //get all your post variables ,save it to database and if successfully saved then build a row
    $returndata ='<tr>';
    $returndata .='<td>'.$division.'</td>';
    //etc...
    $returndata .='<tr>';


    just echo it
    echo $returndata;exit;    
    }
```